# How to apply CSS style for the current page link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

How can I apply a class for the current page link so the mouse cursor will use the default and not the hand?

I don't want to use default cursor on all hovers. I want to apply a class to the active list item and then use default cursor (i.e for "Home" index.html) use default cursor for Home when on home page. Thanks!

Comment: does your site change pages (use more than one page)? or is this one of those "single-paged" sites?

Comment: I will have three pages at some point. I didn't want to have dead links so I used index.html for all menu items.

Comment: Take a look at the `:target` pseudo-selector. http://thinkvitamin.com/design/stay-on-target/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wzDNz/)

---

first, you need to "ID the body" for every page, giving it a distinction what page you are at.

```
//when at home page

<body id="home"> //or services or contact
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li class="home">
            <a> and so on...
        <li class="services">
            <a> and so on...
```

then, you need to add classes for the "current" pages.

```
//if literally spoken, it's "when at 'this' page, style the link with 'this' class"

#home .home,            //style the home link as "current" when body ID is "home"
#services .services,    //style services link as "current" when body ID is "services"
#contact .contact {     //style contact link as "current" when body ID is "contact"
    //styles when current
}
```

Comment: I guess you guys are miss understanding me. I don't want to use default cursor on all hovers. I want to apply a class to the active list item and then use default cursor (i.e for "Home" index.html) use default cursor for Home when on home page. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Joseph, I have no idea on what you are trying to do. It would be easier to remove the href out of each list item for the current page.

Comment: In fact, that solved my problem. I made a class called .displaynone and set display:none. I then applied the class to the list item "Home". It worked great. I will give you credit for inspiring me. Thanks!

Comment: added a demo and see for yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your hover state

```
cursor: default;
```

so something like

```
#list2 a span:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

In most cases, `default` will give you the arrow, which is what I assume that you want.

More details here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cursor

Comment: I guess you guys are miss understanding me. I don't want to use default cursor on all hovers. I want to apply a class to the active list item and then use default cursor (i.e for "Home" index.html) use default cursor for Home when on home page. Thanks!

Comment: The word "active" which you used in the question was apparently ambiguous. Our misunderstanding is just caused by your bad terminology.

Comment: Maybe it was my bad terminology. Now that you understand me, do you have a solution to my post?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the CSS `cursor` property.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Try:

```
div#nav ul li a {
cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: I guess you guys are miss understanding me. I don't want to use default cursor on all hovers. I want to apply a class to the active list item and then use default cursor (i.e for "Home" index.html) use default cursor for Home when on home page. Thanks!